What are some references demonstrating term enumeration of a constructive set theory?
Short and sweet, I would like to see an example (with some explanation) of a term enumeration of a constructive set theory, mainly because I want to appreciate the difference between that and ZFC.
This is probably a very good start for me to read.
The main question is about, if we have a collection of axioms that can essentially act as “formation rules”, is there an abstract way of looking at their “type signatures” (I mean, a formation rule is a function with a domain and codomain, hence it only acts on certain “types”), to decide if they are enumerable or not?
If I have a formation rule that is something like, “for any set $S$, you may form the set $\{S\}$”, it should be easy to enumerate all its terms. Take an initial element, and apply the formation rule to produce a new element. Now, apply it again, to the new element. Ad infinitum.
But if I have a formation rule like, “for any sets $S$ and $T$, form the set $\{S, T\}$”, I don’t know if there’s a necessarily obvious way to enumerate all its terms. Since it has 2 arguments, for a collection of $n$ initial terms, we will have $n^2$ possible input arrangements. Well, perhaps that is a nested iteration: for all i in n: for all j in n: f(i,j).
My hope is to see the axioms of a constructive set theory where by looking at the “type signatures” (the type of the domain and the codomain of each formation rule), you could more clearly and easily see how they might be “chained together” to enumerate all terms, or if not, prove why it is impossible. Thank you.
